Getting file descriptors within kernel space without open()
I want to get file descriptor in linux kernel (6.1.0), but I can't use open() within libc.
To be more precise, I want read /dev/mem.

/dev/mem is a userspace interface to the machine's physical memory.  From the kernel, you use kernel interfaces.
